# Is it useful to improve answered graphics-oriented questions with an illustration?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

For example, in this random question: [My rotated image doesn't have sharp edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217153/my-rotated-image-doesnt-have-sharp-edges) , right now the link is still alive, but it's not on imgur like other images on SE. Would these questions benefit from having a good quality image hosted on imgur ?

More generally, I don't expect code posted in questions to compile. But code posted in answers, except if noted explicitely as pseudo-code or if it contains more ellipsis than letters, should compile.  Is it a waste of time to illustrate answers with actual results?

Comment: Note: I've added the image into the question using the standard stack.imgur location. I missed that during an earlier cleanup I performed on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to include the picture into the post if:

- the picture helps to understand my question/answer better;
- the picture is of a moderate size.

I need to elaborate about the size. Pictures that are too big (e.g. a 1920x1080 screenshot) should not really be included "as is" simply because they are going to be reduced to fit, thus it will be very hard to see anything on them. In this case it's better to either leave a link, or a small thumbnail and a link on the full-sized version.

Please don't include pictures of your code in your IDE. I've seen a couple of such questions, and they are very hard to read. Code should always be presented as text. That pretty much goes with all other text information, unless the picture shows something really important that can't be represented with plain text. For example if your question is about bad text rendering, it may be a good idea to ad an image showing the issue.

Comment: Just for clarification, I'm talking about showing the actual result of a graphics program/snippet, not a screenshot of code in the IDE.

Comment: @Antoine, I know, just had to add that part because some people do that.